# CORS issues on Azure Search Service

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I’m trying to make a GET request in order to query data from Azure Search service. I am trying to follw this tutorial:https://www.dotnetcurry.com/microsoft-azure/cognitive-search-rest-apis-angular-app

How can I allow my domain to make a successful GET request without being blocked by CORS policy.

[image]
Is there a possible way or custom configuration on Azure to allow default sites to bypass this error? I have tried to add the API key as a parameter to the URL but the same problem raised again.

Thank you

Comment: do you get any 403 above this CORS error  in the browser console logs?

Comment: You are calling azure service from localhost right?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you could expand the console errors and update the question. 
@Berkay - Looking at the errors, it appears so  he is calling the azure service from the localhost

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You see this message because your browser blocks requests going to host `samplecognitive.search.windows.net` which is different from the origin `localhost`. You must tell Azure Search to send back a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header including localhost.

In the Overview tab of Azure Search Service go to "Indexes" and click on your index. Then go to "CORS". Add `http://localhost:4200` and click "Save".

[image]